# Nesting a while loop in a for loop

Tags: python, list, encryption, nested-loops, caesar-cipher

I am trying to build a program to decipher a Caesar encryption and iterate through every shift before moving to the next line. The strings to be deciphered are in a list. My problem is i want it to decipher the list at index 0 before moving to to index 1 and so on. For simplicity sake, i just made a list of some random strings that are encrypted.
This is what i have tried and it stops running after finishing index 0

```
import string


def decrypt(encrypted):
    key = 0
    for j in encrypted:
        while key <= 26:
            key += 1
            strline = j
            alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase
            shifted = alphabet[key:] + alphabet[:key]
            shift_table = str.maketrans(alphabet, shifted)
            deciphered = strline.translate(shift_table)
            print(deciphered)


encrypted_list = ["IRMAHG BL YNG", "UTGTGTL TKX RXEEHP", "VABVDXG BL YHHW"]
decrypt(encrypted_list)
```

Comment: You need to reset the value of `key` back to zero before continuing the `while` loop. In other words `key = 0` should probably be on the line after `for j in encrypted:`.

Comment: Another method is not to use `key` (it should be `keyIndex` anyway) but to simply use `j % 26` or, for a cleaner way of programming `j % len(alphabet)`

Comment: Replacing the `while` with `for key in range(26)` seems like a simpler way to produce those values.